# HTML - clickable area

Tags: html

For my navigation bar, how would I make the "Arc Studios" text clickable.

Here's [a pic of the navigation bar](http://prntscr.com/1verqq).

Here's the code;

```
<li id="navbar-logo"><a href="#"></a>Arc Studios</li>
```

So how do I make a clickable link, and add CSS to the text?

```
.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.menu {
    margin-top: -8px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute; right: 0; left: 0;
    text-align: left;

    background: rgb(63,76,107); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%, rgba(63,76,107,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(63,76,107,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(63,76,107,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%,rgba(63,76,107,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%,rgba(63,76,107,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%,rgba(63,76,107,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%,rgba(63,76,107,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3f4c6b', endColorstr='#3f4c6b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #000000;

    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

.menu li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}

.menu li a { /* Navigation Bar text */
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 15px 0;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;

    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;

    color: #FFFFFF;
    /* text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3); */

    -webkit-transition: color .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .4s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:first-child a{ border-left: none; }
.menu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }
.menu li:hover > a { text-decoration: underline; }

.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(63,76,107,1);

    border-left: 1px solid #393942;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #393942;
    border-right: 1px solid #393942;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
    border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .75s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .75s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .75s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .75s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .75s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
}

.menu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 35px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    margin: 0;

    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}

.menu ul li:last-child a {
    border: none;
}

.menu li#navbar-logo {
    color: #FFC8C8;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: Intrique Script Personal Use;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.menu li#navbar-home,
.menu li#navbar-about,
.menu li#navbar-shop,
.menu li#navbar-contact,
.menu li#navbar-community {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.menu li#navbar-logo,
.menu li#navbar-home,
.menu li#navbar-about,
.menu li#navbar-shop,
.menu li#navbar-contact,
.menu li#navbar-community {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

here is the css as requested

Comment: Why don't you put the text into the link tag?

Comment: I tried, I can't add the CSS effects then.

Comment: Which CSS effects? Please post the CSS code.

Comment: @Arc Yes you can, just target the anchor instead of the li.

Comment: @GrailsGuy please forgive me for my ignorance, I'm new to HTML5, how would I do that. Can you post a link or tutorial please?

Comment: @Arc Actually if you post your CSS code, we can help you sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li id="navbar-logo"><a href="#">Arc Studios</a></li>
```

and to add CSS corresponding this html

```
#navbar-logo{
   background-color: blue; //add CSS here
 }
```

your answer is something like that... 
this may help you http://www.w3schools.com/ 
use it.. it helps you a lot

but here "Arc Studio" in that link is not a text .. it is an image .. you can use a image as link

```
<a href="#">
<img src="your_image.jpg"  width="32" height="32"></a>
```

it may help you http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_imglink

Comment: Thank you for this answer, sorry I asked the stupid question, but this one actually helped me, thanks again :)

Comment: @ARC  no question is stupid... sometimes it happens.. the more you ask, the more you learn..never feel hazard .. sometimes it is tough to express the question properly.. but someone will definitely come to help you .. no matter how stupid the question is .. this is just my opinion... :)

Answer (score 1):

Put text inside <a> and </a>

```
<li id="navbar-logo"><a href="#" class='yourClass'>Arc Studios</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

> An anchor tag can't be bind with onClick event. To do that you have to remove "href" from anchor tag. Then it will work without any problem.

```
<li id="navbar-logo"><a class='yourClass'>Arc Studios</a></li>
```